# st_intersects errors for st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, tigris

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(tigris) 
library(sf)
santacruz <- tracts("CA", "Santa Cruz")
coords_sf <- locations %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs=4269)
```

This should have the same CRS, but when I try

```
st_intersects(coords_sf, santacruz)
```

I get

> Error: st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

I then tried

```
st_set_crs(santacruz, 4269)
st_set_crs(coords_sf, 4269)
st_transform(santacruz, 4269)
st_transform(coords_sf, 4269)
```

and it doesn't work.  I also tried

```
st_transform(santacruz, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")

st_transform(coords_sf, crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")
```

No matter what I try with setting CRS and transforming it when I try

```
st_intersects(coords_sf, santacruz)
```

I get

> Error: st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

At this point I can't tell if it is something wrong with setting CRS or transforming or the `st_intersects` function. Thanks,

Comment: What is `locations`?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with sample points from `locations`? One thing is that `tigris` doesn't provide `sf` class objects by default unless you set a global option, otherwise it will be a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Try `santacruz = tigris::tracts("CA", "Santa Cruz", class = "sf")`? In particular, what is the result of `st_crs(santacruz)`?

Comment: I forgot to list it in my write up, but I had `options(tigris_class = "sf")`   However, when I add `santacruz <- st_as_sf(santacruz) %>% st_set_crs(4269)`  It works.                                                                                               Before  when I was getting errors I was seeing `> st_crs(santacruz)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4269 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"
> st_crs(coords_sf)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4269 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
st_set_crs(santacruz, 4269)
```

sets the CRS of the returned object, but does not replace `santacruz`. You need to save it:

```
santacruz <- st_set_crs(santacruz, 4269)
```

or alternatively do

```
st_crs(santacruz) <- 4269
```

to replace the CRS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your location data, but if I try with sf's nc dataset, this works for me:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(tigris) 
library(sf)
santacruz <- tracts("CA", "Santa Cruz")
santacruz <- st_as_sf(santacruz) %>% st_set_crs(4269)
nc <- st_read(system.file('shape/nc.shp', package = 'sf')) %>%
  st_transform(4269)
st_intersects(nc, santacruz)

#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 100, where the predicate was `intersects'
#> first 10 elements:
#>  1: (empty)
#>  2: (empty)
 #> 3: (empty)
 #> 4: (empty)
 #> 5: (empty)
 #> 6: (empty)
 #> 7: (empty)
 #> 8: (empty)
 #> 9: (empty)
 #> 10: (empty)
```

Note this does st_as_sf before st_set_crs on the santacruz object.